# How to allow some permission and not other using a bitwise system?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, acl, bitwise-operators, user-permissions

I am very interested in writing a class that will help me with different permissions for different users (ie. ACL class.)
I have been researching for a great method and bitwise operation stuck out!

I found a good article [How to write a permission system using bits and bitwise operations in PHP](http://codingrecipes.com/how-to-write-a-permission-system-using-bits-and-bitwise-operations-in-php). The article explains How to handle permissions using bitwise operation.

The only thing that I am not sure on how to do is how to allow a user to write a comment but not post a thread.

so if the permission are set like so:

```
<?php
 
    $perms = array(
        'can_post' => 1,
        'can_comment' => 2,
        'can_edit' => 4,
        'can_delete' => 8
    );


   $user_perms = 2;    

//CONDITION #1
if ($user_perms & $perms['can_comment']) {
    /* He/She has permission to do this */
} else {
    /* He/She doesn't have permission */
}


//CONDITION #2
if ($user_perms & $perms['can_post']) {
    /* He/She has permission to do this */
} else {
    /* He/She doesn't have permission */
}

?>
```

so above `CONDITION #1` show work fine and the comments should be allowed but `//CONDITION #2` should not be allowed because The user does not have a permission to post!

My question, how to allow a user to only comment but not post? to post you will have '001' and to comment you will have '010'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your `$perms` array defined, you can actually create your own maps from it:

```
// can comment and post but not edit or delete:
$poster = $perms['can_post'] | $perms['can_comment'];

// can edit and delete, but not comment or post:
$janitor = $perms['can_delete'] | $perms['can_edit'];
```

You can combine any number of permissions with the `|` operator to build permission values.

Comment: Does this work for decimal numbers or only binary numbers? I do not see any binary operations above?

Comment: @andrebruton It will only work if each permission is a power of two. That said, you could have some cleverness, say `$perms['general_posting'] = 3;` to have permissions that automatically activate more than one base permission flag.